# How do you override the database collation in a query when using Sybase?

Tags: sql, collation, sybase-asa

For example when using a SQL server database that has a default collation of case insensitive I can override that collation in a query to get a case sensitive comparison like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyColumn LIKE '%test%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

How would achieve the same thing in a Sybase database that is also set to default to case insensitive?

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be done without changing the sort order.  There is a Dictionary Order, Case Sensitive, with Preference that may allow you to get the results you want without messing up where clauses that rely on case insensitivity.

Comment: Also, what Sybase product are you running?  ASE? ASA? IQ?

Comment: ASA version 8 I think, connecting to it via SSIS. It is part of a third-party application and I can't make any changes to the database. One option might be to let SSIS do the filtering and just do a case insensitive prefilter in a query. The problem is that I am trying to correct some common errors in a text field and few involve just changing the case - therefore my rows to process would never decrease.

Answer (score 0):

This question is almost touching the tender age of 10 years, but is exactly what I was searching for. In my case I didn't need a like, but a simple equals:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyColumn = 'test'
AND hash(MyColumn) = hash('test') -- hash('TEST') would be different
```

The hash() enforces case-sensitivity (and, yes, slows down the query tremendously!)